# Partial permutation with repetition. List all solutions algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, permutation, partial

I will be looking for your best advice and recommendations. I have a problem with different box and object.

Let me explain: For example, I have 2 box and 3 objects. So I count all solutions with 2^3 = 8 possible solutions. List of box `{-1, 0}`. List of objects `{0, 1, 2}`.

My representation for one solution: an array[objects.length]

```
1 solution : [-1,-1,-1];
2 solution : [0,-1,-1];
3 solution : [-1,0,-1];
4 solution : [-1,-1,0];
5 solution : [0,0,-1];
6 solution : [-1,0,0];
7 solution : [0,-1,0];
8 solution : [0,0,0];
```

Now I present my algorithm that doesn't work:

```
Array box = {-1, 1}
Array object = {0, 1, 2}
Array solutions = {}

// INITIALISATION
Stack sbox = box;
Stack sobject = object;

WHILE sobject not empty DO
     object = Pop sobject;

     FOR i from 0 to box.length DO
          solution[object] = box[i];
     FIN POUR
END WHILE
```

But this solution is not correct because I have just 6 solutions.

Can you help me with different document or advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your box array is {-1, 0}, anyway the code below works. You just need a radix (the number of boxes) then divide the total number of permutations over and over again. In your case, you have 2^3=8 solutions, your radix is 2, you try 0, 1, 2, .. 7 in the outer loop, and divide the radix in the inner loop.

```
    int[] box = {-1, 0};
    int objects = 3;
    int total = (int) Math.pow(box.length, objects);
    int radix = box.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        int v = i;
        for (int pos = 0; pos < objects; pos++) {
            System.out.print(box[v % radix] + " ");
            v = v / radix;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This way, you can avoid a big stack when you have a lot of boxes (recursion also requires the stack). In more complicated cases, you could have multiple radices, e,g. for the 1st box, item A and B are allowed, for the 2nd box, B, C and D are allowed.

Comment: Thanks daniel, this approach is different but it's too, thaks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Give your boxes the numbers 0...n

Number of objects: m

Than you can simply count in numbers to base n and use the resulting digits to determine in which box to put each object. Simply count from `0` to `m^n-1` to get all combinations.

Example number of boxes 3, number of objects 4

```
0000    all in boy 0
0001    fist three in box 0 last one in box 1
0002
0010
0011
0012
0020    fist two in box 0, third one in box 2 and last one in box 0
...
2210    fist two in box 2, third one in box 1 and last one in box 0
2211
2212
2220
2221
2222
```

This way you get all `m^n` possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably a recursive function.

Basically, for each index (object), try all possible elements (boxes), then recurse onto the next index.

```java
box = {-1, 0}
objectCount = 3
solutions = {}

getPermutations(0, new array[objectCount]) // function call

getPermutations(index, output)
   if index == output.length
      solutions.add(output)
   else
      for each box b
         output[index] = b
         getPermutations(index + 1, output)
```

[Live Java demo](http://ideone.com/oGBEQo).

Comment: I translated your code to [C++](http://ideone.com/6FwFt9) and added it to the answer, I figured it could be useful to someone. Thank you !